# Почему getline() не считывает первую строку файла?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте. В чём тут проблема? Объясните пожалуйста.
В файле "paths" содержатся строки, которые записаны в формате:

```
C:\1
C:\2
C:\3
C:\4
C:\5
```

Т.е. каждая строка друг за дружкой, но считываются почему-то все, кроме первой строки и в конце ещё пустая строка добавляется, a если оставить только одну строку в файле, то она нормально считается без пустой строки в конце. В чём проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path;
    ifstream file("D:\\paths.txt");
    {
        while (getline(file, path))
        {
            file >> path;
            cout << path << "\n";
        }
    }
    file.close();
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что считывание происходит два раза:

- при вызове метода [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline): `while (getline(file, path))`
- при вызове оператора [`>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) экземпляра класса [`ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream): `file >> path;`

Исправить можно убрав второе считывание.

---

Немного подробнее:

- До начала цикла [`while`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while) "курсор", соответствующий текущей позиции в файле, находится в начале файла (курсор обозначен вертикальной чертой `|`):

  ```
  |C:\1
  C:\2
  C:\3
  ```
- После первого вызова `getline` происходит считывание всей первой строки и курсор перемещается на вторую строку:

  ```
  C:\1
  |C:\2
  C:\3
  ```
- После первого выполнения `file >> path` **предыдущее значение переменной `path` теряется** (а это как раз вся первая строчка), и считывается следующий токен (в конце ответа немного написано про отличие `>>` и `getline`), курсор перемещается в конец второй строки:

  ```
  C:\1
  C:\2|
  C:\3
  ```
- При втором вызове `getline` происходит считывание строки, но так как курсор находится в конце строки, то считывается пустая строка, курсор перемещается в начало следующей строки:

  ```
  C:\1
  C:\2
  |C:\3
  ```
- Далее аналогично каждый вызов `file >> path` считывает строку и перемещает курсор в конец строки, каждый вызов `getline(file, path)` считывает пустую строку и перемещает курсор из конца строки в начало следующей строки.

---

Про отличие `getline` и `>>`:

- оператор `поток_stream >> переменная_типа_string` считывает строку так: сначала пропускаются все пробельные символы, затем происходит считывание пока не встретится пробельный символ (пробельные символы это пробел , перенос строки `\n`, таб `\t` и другие)
- `getline` ничего не пропускает, а просто считывает строку до первого символа переноса строки